# Qt - Background Image behind child widgets

Tags: python, pyqt, qtstylesheets

I have a Qt interface with a:

- QWidget
- QVBoxLayout
- QMainLayout
- QPushButton

My interface is something like this:

```
BACKGROUND_IMAGE_URL = "D:/image.png"
w = QWidget()
w.setStyleSheet("background-image:" + "url(" + BACKGROUND_IMAGE_URL + ");" + "border:0px")
w.repaint()
w.show()

button = QPushButton("btn1")
button.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border:0px")

verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout()
verticalLayout.addWidget(button)
mainLayout = QGridLayout()
mainLayout.addLayout(verticalLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1)
w.setLayout(self.mainLayout)
```

i.e. a widget with a button. The widget background is an image. The button background should be white, but due to the widget background image, the button stylesheet doesn't show up at all.

I would like the button background to go ON TOP of the widget background image. Any thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: what is BACKGROUND_IMAGE_URL?

Comment: What if you `w.show()` after `w.setLayout`?

Comment: see my latest change. just a file url

Comment: show after set layout doesn't make a difference. still can't see white background for button. note that if ``w.setStylesheet()`` uses a background-color instead of background-image then button background-color will be viewable

Comment: It works for me, try the following: copy the image next to the .py and change to BACKGROUND_IMAGE_URL = "image.png"

Comment: the issue is not that the background image isn't showing. the issue is that the button background doesn't show

Comment: okay, I understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is caused because the background image is going to be applied to all the widgets so the color of the button is not modified. One solution is to apply the background image only to the widget, so we use the [`.` selector](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types):

```
w.setStyleSheet(".QWidget{background-image:" + "url(" + BACKGROUND_IMAGE_URL + ");" + "border:0px}")
```